# Python Selenium hard webscraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

website is: https://www.jao.eu/auctions#/

you see 'OUT AREA' dropdown (I see a lot of ReactSelect...)

I need to get the full list of items contained in that list [AT, BDL-GB, BDL-NL, BE...].

Can you please help me?

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('https://www.jao.eu/auctions#/')

first = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.css-1739xgv-control')))

first.click()

                                                                          
second = wait.until(......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging ones network traffic reveals that the page makes several requests to REST APIs, one endpoint being `getcorridors`,  whose response is JSON and contains all values from the dropdown(s). All you need to do is imitate that HTTP POST request. No Selenium required:

```
def get_corridors():
    import requests
    from operator import itemgetter

    url = "https://www.jao.eu/api/v1/auction/calls/getcorridors"

    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json={})
    response.raise_for_status()

    return list(map(itemgetter("value"), response.json()))
    

def main():

    for corridor in get_corridors():
        print(corridor)
    
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
IT-CH
HU-SK
ES-PT
FR-IT
SK-CZ
NL-DK
IT-FR
HU-HR
FR-ES
IT-GR
CZ-AT
DK-NL
SI-AT
CH-DE
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to fetch the required list of items from that site using requests module:

```
import requests

link = 'https://www.jao.eu/api/v1/auction/calls/getcorridors'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.post(link,json={})
    items = [item['value'] for item in res.json()]
    print(items)
```

Output are like (truncated):

```
'IT-CH', 'HU-SK', 'ES-PT', 'FR-IT', 'SK-CZ', 'NL-DK', 'IT-FR', 'HU-HR'
```

Comment: @paul-m
Thank you, this is awesome. But I also need to scrape the tables present in https://www.jao.eu/auctions#/ after I select OUT AREA, IN AREA, TYPE, AUCTION ID, etc... Can you please help me?

Comment: That is beyond the scope of your question you asked in the first place. Please, try creating another post describing your new requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, please check my next post on this regard. I need your help please